# How do I call asp.net 3.5 soap xml based webservice in javascript or jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, web-services

I am new in jquery and trying to consume asp.net 3.5 made webservice in Jquery but i don't know why i can't use it.
all the examples that i found over the internet are same as i'm doing, but i don't know whats happening to the code,

can anybody please help me ?

here is my javascript code,

```
var soapMessage =
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
    <soap:Body> \
    <test xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> \
    <param>this is a test parameter</param> \
    </test> \
    </soap:Body> \
    </soap:Envelope>';

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:50575/Service1.asmx?op=test",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapMessage,
        complete: hi,
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert("error");
        },
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });

    function hi(xmlHttpRequest, status) {

        alert($(xmlHttpRequest.responseText).text());

        alert($(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).find('Mymessage').text());

    }
```

and here is server side code

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{


    [WebMethod]
    public message test(string param)
    {
        message mymsg = new message();
        mymsg.head = "message head";
        mymsg.Mymessage = "Test string with param " + param;
        return mymsg;
    }
```

Comment: What values do you get for a, b, and c in your error handler?

Comment: a is [object Object]
b is "error"
and c is empty

Answer (score 0):

The first object passed to the error handler should contain some useful information.  Try to "expand" a in whatever debugging tool you're using.  Don't just 'alert' its value.

Specifically, look for `a.status` and `a.responseText`.  This should give you a good idea of what's going on.

Comment: a.status is 0 and a.responseText is empty

Comment: how do id debug javascript?
for now i am checking the result by using alerts.

Comment: Well, that's weird.  Have you tried attaching a debugger to the server side code to see if anything happens at all on the server side?  Can you post your server-side code?

Comment: i have updated my question with server side code,
please have a look

Comment: i have attached a debuger in server side but it never come to the debug point,

Comment: i think Jquery/Javascript not reached to the url

Comment: Try setting `contentType` to xml as well.  Do some research and see if you could be using the wrong value for `contentType`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you give [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) a try, which is a great web debugging tool and should help you a lot with identifying the problem you had.